# Taking a portion of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Given a list of numbers, e.g. `aa={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}; bb={6,7}`, how do I take the portion of the list that matches a particular pattern, for example, "6,7". I tried

```
ix=Position[aa,#]/@bb
newaa=aa[[ix;;Length[aa]]]
```

and was not not a valid span specification. Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: try `SequencePosition[aa, bb]` and/or `SequenceCases[aa, bb]`?

Comment: The real issue is not whether I can determine the position of this pattern, indeed ix=Position[aa,bb] does, but it is given in the form of {{ }} which cannot be used in the subsequent statement, i.e., newaa=aa[[ix;;Length[aa]]] because aa is given as {{13}}, not suitable as a "valid span specification".

Comment: what is the desired result  (`newaa`)? Is it `{6, 7, 8, 9, 10}`?

Comment: The portion of the list after 6,7 should be {8,9,10} or if I get {6,7,8,9,10} that would be acceptable also.

Comment: Z Ming Ma, posted an answer showing how to use  `SequenceCases` and `SequencePosition` to get the desired result.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by “...take the portion of the list...”? Do you wish to remove it from the list and have what remains? Or do you wish to have the portion of the list that follows the desired sequence pattern? Please, can you clarify this?

Comment: Please allow me to clarify. I meant to find the pattern that remarcates the end of the first portion and before beginning of the second portion which is what I want. Thanks to the multiple solutions members of the Stack Exchange offered, I have been able to accomplish the desired results.

Comment: There is, however, one puzzle I still have resolved, namely, the use of First@ or Last@ which seemed to solve the essential difficulty I had, i.e., I was able to get the position of the demarcating pattern except it  was wrapped in two pairs of curly brackets. As such I was not able to use it as span indicator. The problem disappeared with First@ or Last@ before Flatten[Position.... I went back to the Book and was unable to find a clue for either of the two curly bracket brackets. Please enlighten.

Comment: The use of `Position` does indeed produce different syntax than one would use in `Span`. You can get around this, however. Maybe I can show a different method than those below.

Comment: As an amateur Mathematica user, I still find it difficult to "read" Mathematica code out loud in the debugging process, as one would with C or Fortran codes. The greatest puzzle here is that I can see the index except it buried two curly brackets deep and could not find it way to liberate it for indexing purpose. What is it that I am missing? THank you for your patience.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
aa = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
bb = {6, 7};
```

**1.** You can use [`SequenceCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCases.html) as follows:

```
First @ SequenceCases[aa, Append[bb, ___]]
```

> ```
>  {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
> ```

Alternatively,

```
First @ SequenceCases[aa, Append[bb, c___] :> {c}]
```

> ```
>  {8, 9, 10}
> ```

**2.** If you have to use `Position`, you can do

```
ix = 1 + Last @ Flatten[Position[aa, #] & /@ bb]
newaa = aa[[ix ;;]]
```

> ```
>  {8, 9, 10}
> ```

**3.** Using [`SequencePosition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequencePosition.html) instead of `Position`:

```
ix2 = 1 + Last @ Flatten @ SequencePosition[aa, bb];
newaa2 = aa[[ix2 ;;]]
```

> ```
>  {8, 9, 10}
> ```

Answer (score 8):

```
SequenceSplit[aa,bb][[2]]
```

> {8, 9, 10}

Comment: I did not even know that existed...

Comment: This is, imo, the canonical answer. “Oh, right, of course there’s a function to do exactly that!”

Answer (score 1):

Another couple of alternative answers, or more variations on a theme, if you will:

```
Last@@SequencePosition[aa,bb]//aa[[#+1;;]]&


aa[[1+Last@##;;]]&@@SequencePosition[aa,bb]

#[[1+Last@@SequencePosition[#,bb];;]]&@aa
```

All give the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

```
aa = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
bb = {6, 7};

Replace[aa, {h___, PatternSequence @@ bb, g___} :> {g}]
```

> {8, 9, 10}

or if you want the pattern as well:

```
Replace[aa, {h___, k : PatternSequence @@ bb, g___} :> {k, g}]
```

> {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

---

Furthermore, `Replace` allows a *levelspec* argument to provide more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

```
aa = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
bb = {6, 7};

Drop[aa, {1, SequencePosition[aa, bb][[-1, -1]]}
```

{8, 9, 10}

Some of the answers give wrong results with a more complicated list.

```
aa = {5, 7, 4, 3, 1, 1, 8, 4, 3, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4};
bb = {4, 3};
```

The sequence `4, 3` occurs twice.

**1.**
Take after last `4, 3`

```
Drop[aa, {1, SequencePosition[aa, bb][[-1, -1]]}]
```

{9, 1, 2, 3, 4}

**2.**
Take after first `4, 3`

```
Drop[aa, {1, SequencePosition[aa, bb][[+1, -1]]}]
```

{1, 1, 8, 4, 3, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4}